# Compass for a trajectory - THREE.js

Tags: html, three.js

I am having a tube trajectory (using three.js) in a canvas. I have added trackballcontrols to the camera so that trajectory can be rotated and zoom -/+.

Now I want to  display a compass showing direction in which the trajectory is facing on the LHS bottom-most corner – it should move as the trajectory moves.

Thanks,
bhupendra

Comment: 1. `TrackballControls` rotates the camera, not the object. 2. Try first. If you have problems, show what you have tried, and ask a specific question.

Comment: I tried adding a compass image via texture and then adding mesh to scene. but the problem is that as other object rotates the image also rotates . it performs all the controls as other object.Should i create separate scene or camera ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226693/three-js-show-world-coordinate-axes-in-corner-of-scene

Comment: ya it worked.@WestLangley thnks

Comment: Can I put lables (like X,Y,Z) on the axes of axis-helper , I tried properties of axishelper but none supports this, does  this require change in three.js lib ?

Comment: If you have another issue, please make a new post, show what you have tried, and ask a specific question.