# How to add AxexHelper at a specifc position in ThreeJs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, graphics, 3d, react-three-fiber

I try to fix position of axeshelper on three js. But it rotates when the scene rotates.

I need to fix the axeshelper at bottom left corner like every 3D application has. How can I set the position for the axeshelper without rotating when the scene rotates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Three.js: Show world coordinate axes in corner of scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226693/three-js-show-world-coordinate-axes-in-corner-of-scene)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.